# AttributeError: module 'httpcore' has no attribute 'SyncHTTPTransport

Tags: python

While importing googletrans I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: module 'httpcore' has no attribute 'SyncHTTPTransport

Answer (score 11, accepted):

googletrans==3.0.0 use very old httpx (0.13.3) and httpcore version. You just need to update httpx and httpcore to latest version and go to googletrans source directory in Python310/Lib/site-packages. In the file client.py, fix '`httpcore.SyncHTTPTransport`' to '`httpcore.AsyncHTTPProxy`'. And done, perfect. Even, Async, a concurrency model that is far more efficient than multi-threading, and can provide significant performance benefits and enable the use of long-lived network connections such as WebSockets.
if you got error 'Nonetype'...group. Try: `pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1`

Comment: sadly been dealing with `googletrans` dep conflicts with another package for `httpx` for 2 days but now thanks to you it's ok now

Answer (score 1):

This is a easy way by patch:

```py
import httpcore
setattr(httpcore, 'SyncHTTPTransport', Any)
```

Comment: Sorry that does not work. NameError: name 'Any' is not defined

Comment: Use
```setattr(httpcore, 'SyncHTTPTransport', 'AsyncHTTPProxy')```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the extra packages and version

```
pip install httpcore==0.15.0 httpx pymongo googletrans
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the sudden I faced this issue. I was using version 4.0.0rc1 for googletrans. It seems googletrans has three dependencies: h11, httpcore, and httpx.

I tried to upgrade googletrans using pip

```
$ pip install googletrans --upgrade
```

It did not upgrade googletrans but downgrade its dependencies.

Now I run the app without any issues. I'm not sure why pip's dependency resolver downgrade the packages, since initially the app was running well with the current versions.