Snowflake package import AttributeError: module 'httpcore' has no attribute 'SyncHTTPTransport' in function
Im importing the googletrans module into snowflake stage and using the import in the snowflake function.I have zipped the package and uploaded into snowflake stage, While creating the function I'm getting error as AttributeError: module 'httpcore' has no attribute 'SyncHTTPTransport' in function.

Used the httcore and httpx versions and getting incomaptible package error:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Do you have code we can copy paste to reproduce?

Whatversion of httpcore are you using - this question addresses the situation regardless of snowflake https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72796594/attributeerror-module-httpcore-has-no-attribute-synchttptransport

which version of httpcore,httpx and python is compatible for this. Please suggest will try with appropriate version

Added the details for the version. Please suggest

Thanks for the screenshot. Can you paste code so we can copy paste it and reproduce, instead of typing it all again?

(the instruction you used to download and package those zip files would be useful too.. please make it easy for us to reproduce, and we'll give you the best we have)
